# python/django - login with google/facebook in our website except using openID

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to make a website which is enable to login with gmail or facebook. I am using python and django framwork. Can anybody give me some idea about how to design and implement.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth), it allows you to use social authentications from many websites like facebook, twitter etc.

Update:
As @Rob Agar mentioned in the comments [django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) has been deprecated and [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) should be used instead.

Comment: The django-social-auth site says it's deprecated in favour of [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth), which it itself uses.

Comment: I noted that I just wanted to keep the original answer in tact I will update the answer to state the deprecation.